# What is wrong with fileOpener2?

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins

This question is edit for better undersatnding:
I am trying to use the cordova fileOpener2 plugin to open pdf files in my app's assets.
I obtain the file's uri thanks to lines 14 and onward of code below.
The uri is then stored as a varialbe (nonencodeduri).
However when I try to use the variable in the second part of the code where FileOpener2 needs the path to the file (from line 58), it stalls. 
This is surprising because if I write hardcode the path to the same file line 58 (var uri = var uri = encodeURI("path to file in the assets of the app"), it works.
Thanks for helping me resolve this.

Here is the full code (credits: Ghandi)

```
var  entry, documentname, documentid, referenceID, callLogID, filePath, blob,cdr,fileObject;
var filename = "test.pdf";


$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

var fileURL = "";
var imagePath = "";
function onDeviceReady() {  
    sessionStorage.platform = device.platform;
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
     $('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function()
        {   
            try {
                alert('Hi boys');   
                var urinonencoded = this.href;
                alert(urinonencoded + ' and voila');                                        
                if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
                }
                else {
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
                }

            }
            catch(err) {
                alert("ER - " + err.message);
            }

        }); 

        function onError(e) {
            alert("onError");
        };

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var entry="";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry=fileSystem;
            }
            else {
                entry=fileSystem.root;
            }           
            entry.getDirectory("Cordova", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
        };
        function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
            dir.getDirectory("Sample_App", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess1, onGetDirectoryFail);
        };
        function onGetDirectorySuccess1(dir) {
            cdr = dir;
            dir.getFile(filename,{create:true, exclusive:false},gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
        };
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {                                      
                /*var uri = encodeURI(myref);*/

                    var uri = urinonencoded;
                    alert (uri);


                alert("dest - " + cdr.nativeURL+filename);
                fileTransfer.download(uri,cdr.nativeURL+filename,
                    function(entry) {                       
                        openFile();
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert("download error source " + error.source);
                        alert("download error target " + error.target);
                        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                        alert("error");
                    },
                    true);              
        };

        function openFile() {
            alert("URL - " + cdr.nativeURL+filename);
            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                cdr.nativeURL+filename, 
                'application/pdf', 
                //'text/plain',
                { 
                    error : function(e) { 
                        alert('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                    },
                    success : function () {                                    
                    }
                }
            );
        };
        function onFileSystemSuccessDelete(fileSystem) {
            var entry="";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry=fileSystem;
            }
            else {
                entry=fileSystem.root;
            }   
            entry.getDirectory("Cordova/Sample_App", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccessDelete, onGetDirectoryFail);

        };
        function onGetDirectorySuccessDelete(dir) {
            dir.getFile(filename,{create: true, exclusive:false},gotFileEntryDelete, fail);                     
        };

        function gotFileEntryDelete(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.remove();
            var uri = encodeURI("http://SERVER_IP:PORT/test.pdf");
                fileTransfer.download(uri,cdr.nativeURL+filename,
                    function(entry) {
                        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());                     
                        openFile();
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert("download error source " + error.source);
                        alert("download error target " + error.target);
                        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                        alert("error");
                    },
                    true);              
        };      

        function fail(error){
            alert("ec - " + error.code);
        };

        function  errorHandler(e) {
            var msg = '';
            switch (e.code) {
                case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                    msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                    msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                    msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                    msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                    msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                    break;
                default:
                    msg = e.code;
                    break;
            };
            alert("Msg - " + msg);
        };

        function onGetDirectoryFail(error) {
            alert("onGetDirectoryFail");
        };

        $('#delete').click(ClearDirectory);

        function ClearDirectory() {
            alert("delete");
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
            }
            else {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
            }        
        }
        function onFileSystemDirSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var entry = "";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry=fileSystem;
            }
            else {
                entry=fileSystem.root;
            }   
            entry.getDirectory("Cordova",{create : true, exclusive : false},
                function(entry) {
                    entry.removeRecursively(function() {
                        console.log("Remove Recursively Succeeded");
                    }, fail);
                }, getDirFail);
        }

        function getDirFail(error){
            alert("getDirFail - " + error.code);
        };

}
```

I used:

```
<script>
    $('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function() {
    var myuri = this.href ;   
        alert(this.href);

  /*alert just to make sure I got the right uri (which works fine)*/

    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        'this.href', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
        'application/pdf', 
        { 
                error : function(e) 
             { 
                alert('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
            },
            success : function () 
            {
                alert('file opened successfully');                
            }
        }
    );
        return false; 
    });

    </script>
```

and it hangs (i have the plugin declared in the config.xml file and present in the assets.

Can you pinpoint my error(s)?

Many thanks

Comment: do you get any errors on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the issue is with the way you pass the `file path` paramter you pass to fileopener's open function and nothing wrong with the plugin as such.

If you pass `this` object inside single quote like `'this.href'`, it will be treated as a plain string and that's the issue. So you can use the approach as Joerg suggested in his answer.

Do check out this [basic working sample app](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations) that demonstrates Cordova file operations. It should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks Gandhi for shiming in. Unfortunately the script still hangs.  wonder if there is not a missing part in this riddle...

Comment: @Needzhelp You can have a look at this sample project - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: Hello Gandhi. Unfortunately there was not much I was able to derive from your WWW. there is one index.html with 3 references to JS libraries. There is also on the git page a reference to some 5 plugins but none are in mentioned in the config.xml but the whitelist plugin. I do not see how I can get anywhere. Can you expand a bit?

Comment: @Needzhelp you gotta install that using Cordova plugin add command as mentioned in readme

Comment: Yes, I can run the the install command for the plugins, but where I go from there? 
I've already done that with my own app. 
I think what  need is working example, to see where I went wrong...Thanks :-)

Comment: @Needzhelp what's uploaded in the page are all working samples. You gotta build the app and generate apk, install in device to see what it actually does. Please try to understand the code once

Comment: @Needzhelp before you try out, ensure to have a URL to access a sample PDF file so that u can use the URL in your app to test

Comment: Gandhin your app says: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/index?html) though it is present...

Comment: @Needzhelp How are you generating apk file? R u testing on actual device? If possible, send your project in github. Wil check tomorrow.

Comment: I am gnerating with cordova CLI. then checking on device (Sony Xperia). I will post project and add a comment here to tell you when it's available on github. Thanks :-) Good night.

Comment: Hello,Here is the project: https://github.com/phdecloitre/project-for-pdf

Comment: @Needzhelp I m out of work. Can get back to u by tomorrow or Monday

Comment: Hi Gandhi, are you still oout there?

Comment: @Needzhelp I m there.. Need device to check it out.. Curree held up on other tasks too

Comment: Ghandi! I finally managed to get your FileDownload app working.

Comment: @Needzhelp that's great news. What was the issue? Did de sample assisted you?

Comment: The sample helped me tremendously! 
Here is what I did: I changed the url (to some server)vthat was hardcoded in your app.js file and put the uri pointing to a file within the app's asset (which I had added). It worked and opened in the device's pdf reader.
Now I'm trying to use your setup so that it works whenever I click on a pdf file hyperlink from any html file in the app.
As a first step I modified  this to your app.js file:
"$('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click"
that is instead of your onclick button to download a file. It works.

Comment: Then I modified this:
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {          
    var uri = encodeURI(path to your server);
and instead of the path to server I wrote 
"this.href" but it deos not work , the app returns an error: download error source null...
thanks for your help!

Comment: @Needzhelp Have updated my answer. Please accept if it helped so that its beneficial for other's room Happy coding. Cheers

Comment: I will accept it as soon as I can get to pass on that href. I tried many ways (with and without quotes). I tried using a var (called myuri in may question above) ; with and without quotes. I tried using "this.href" (with and without quotes. None work, Can you adivse?

Comment: Ghandi, Why do you think your app returns "download error source null" eventhough I was apble to capture the this.href data and have the app show it in the alert box (alert(this.ref). When I tell the script to fetch the file manually it works (if I hardcode tha path to the file instead of  this.href) . So the file exists and can be red. Why does it not recognize this.href?

Comment: @Needzhelp could you update the code you are trying in your question?

Comment: @Needzhelp HI, the issue is that urinonencoded variable needs to be declared globally just like 'entry', 'filepath' variables

Comment: Thank you Ghandi. I figured that one out last night. It is working now. I've come up with a complete answer which I added and I upped your answer. Great job! Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Needzhelp I m glad that i could help you out. Happy coding.. Cheers... Hope to cya soon.. tc

Comment: Gandhi, are you still outthere? I am trying to use your script for 2 different cases (pdf and mp3) I can make each script work separately bu I cannot have them work together in an if/else structure (wichever part of the script is loaded last overrides the other) 
Cheers

Comment: @Needzhelp sorry to say this that you can't simply unaccept the answer when you face a problem. That don't motivates either. May be it can be new question. It requires time and effort to debug and resolve issues. Reputation points is what motivates me in SO and I don see that happening in this instance.

Comment: I did not unaccept ypur answer. If i did it's a bad mistake on my part. On the contrary i'm very grateful for your help. Where is it that i unaccepted? Can i correct it? All my best

Comment: @Needzhelp Thought it was intentional. You have accepted your own answer that shows a green tick next to your answer. Earlier it was showing mine as accepted with the green tick next to upvote. And to resolve your issue, you may have to share your problematic code may be as a new question. Cheers

Comment: I think I corrected the wrong (it was just a wild click). :-)

Answer (score 1):

'this.href' is wrong, try it this way:

```
$('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function () {
    var myuri = this.href;
    alert(this.href);

    /*alert just to make sure I got the right uri (which works fine)*/

    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        myuri, // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
        'application/pdf',
        {
            error: function (e) {
                alert('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('file opened successfully');
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your coorection. 
However, I altered the script accordingly but the script stillhalts after the file path alert (alert (this.href).
Does fileOpener2 really have the capacity to open asset-located files?
Many thanks

Comment: Joer, I checked and it appears FileOpener cannot open asset files (which is where my href points to (it points to file:///android_assets/www/res/somefile.pdf). So I tried with hardccoding the path and wrote :see below

Comment: cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(sdcard/Download/DOC.pdf, 
    'application/pdf', 
 { 
         error : function(e) 
       { 
            alert('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () 
        {
            alert('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);

Comment: Unforutnately although the path and file exist, FilOpener does not budge. 
I declared fileOpener2 in the config.xml file, and it is in the assets. Should it be also declared in the html page?

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the answers for this complex problem:
**first**: fileopener2 will not work on its own, it needs other plugins to fit the purpose of opening pdf files on android. The other plugins needed are mentioned in Gandhi's excellent demo app available [here](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations).
**Second**: it is esssentiel to use Gandhi's app.js file that combines the different calls to plugins.
**Third** there are a number of functions involved in that file. In it the path is hard-coded, so everything seems to work well. But if you must use a dynamic path, then it must be stated globally (in other words, do not use "var" but simply myvar = this.href.

Although I found the last bits on my own, all the credit goes to Gandhi's excellent demo app which is a treasure trove for new plugin users he made available on github. +1 :-)

Comment: I think I corrected the wrong (it was just a wild click). :-)

Comment: Guess so.Please post your issue with code in a new post. Will check out. Cheers

Comment: It was already addressed by vld here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983151/one-javascript-script-derails-another-though-not-adressing-the-same-element-wh I was not able to use your script for diferent types pf files at the same time (parallelly) The solution was to embed each into a wrapping like so: (function(){ /* file contents go here */ })() Many thanks, though, I will probably be soon back with new questions ;-)

Comment: Great then. Happy coding